# jquery plugin options not reading

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm pretty new to jquery and I'm creating my first plugin but running into a problem. I'm able to get it working fine but when I add in options to my function it doesn't seem to be reading it properly. For example I have the **slideshowTransition** option but it doesn't seem to be reading it in my **rotateImages** function. I'm able to output it to the console fine but have no idea why it's not reading. See the code below:

```
(function($){
 $.fn.imageRotator = function(config, slideshowSpeed) {

$.imageRotator = {
    defaults: {
    slideshowSpeed: '3000',
            slideshowTransition: '4000'
    }
};

settings = $.extend({}, $.imageRotator.defaults, config); 

//loop back to the top once rotateimages function is complete       
setInterval(rotateImages, settings.slideshowSpeed); 

function rotateImages(config){

var currentPhoto = $("#photo_slideshow .current");
var nextPhoto = currentPhoto.next();

//used to loop back to the top once the last image is finished
if(nextPhoto.length == 0){
    nextPhoto = $("#photo_slideshow div:first");
}

currentPhoto.removeClass('current').addClass('previous');

console.log(settings.slideshowSpeed);


//take what's next make it visible and move it on top
nextPhoto.css({ opacity: 0 }).addClass('current').animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, settings.slideshowTransition, 


    //callback function to drop photo down to the bottom of the z-index
    function(){

    currentPhoto.removeClass('previous');

    }
)
};
//end rotate images function

};

})(jQuery);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding about your question is, you have a problem in calling the plugin function with parameters passed, If that is so , please have a look in this link

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/kDg3A/1/
```

i have just added code for your reference.

Comment: Thanks for replying @Ravi but when I add in the options  to this line of code **nextPhoto.css({ opacity: 0 }).addClass('current').animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, settings.slideshowTransition,** the "settings.slideshowTransition" option isn't reading. Any idea why?

Comment: hi delmon, 
 i am not sure, why you are not getting the value of settings.slideshowTransition, can you post your code and related html and function call stuffs in jsfiddle, will have a look and help you what ever i can

Comment: hey @ravi. Sorry I haven't been able to post this until now. Here is my code in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghowell/d5P9n/. I'm able to print to the console the value of **settings.slideshowTransition** but the last line of my code which starts with nextPhoto.css is unable to read it.

Comment: function call should be after the function definition,
http://jsfiddle.net/d5P9n/1/